# .gif is not responding in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I get blank screen when i run this code.

```
screen=turtle.Screen()
print(screen.bgpic())
screen.setup(900, 650)
screen.bgpic("map.gif")
input()
```

Posting the image below

[Full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aGTN.png)

[Blank Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdi3U.png)

Comment: the screen windows not responding so there probably an error, can you post the console output ? or delete the print(screen.bgpic()) line

Comment: @LinhNguyen   print(screen.bgpic()) will show nopic as i didn't place any background pic so if i delete this line there is no change in output still the screen window will show blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to have input() ? you can just run like this and it should show up:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(900, 650)
screen.bgpic("map.gif")

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: i use input to stop the screen window from disappearing.

Comment: you can try to add turtle.exitonclick() at the end to control when it close

Comment: Thanks a ton @Linh Nguyen . Now its showing the image

Comment: glad to help :), you can accept it as an answer if it worked